# filter out strings in a (string [] list)

Tags: arrays, list, filter, f#, conditional-statements

I wish to filter out strings in a list of string array (String [] list)

I tried with

```
|> List.map (fun x->  Array.filter (fun x -> x = condition))
```

but it dosent work

can someone please help?

thanks

EDIT (make it clearer)

Input

```
[[|hi,hello,hello|],[|hello,hi,hello|],[|hi,hi,hello|]]
```

output (filter out hi)

```
[[|hello,hello|],[|hello,hello|],[|hello|]]
```

Comment: can you give us a full example of input/desired output? What is the problem with the partial expression you did provide? What is `condition`?

Comment: BTW: assuming `condition`is a string then there is a parameter missing for `Array.filter` - try `yourList |> List.map (Array.filter ((=)  condition))` this is a curried version of `yourList |> List.map (fun ls -> Array.filter (fun x -> condition = x) ls)`

Comment: if on the other hand `condition` is supposed to be a predicate (`string -> bool`) then you need: `yourList |> List.map (Array.filter condition)`

Comment: I added an example of the desired output...

Comment: hmm the problem with our code is that I need to call a function with x as a parameter to compare it with the "condition"

Comment: se my answer - this gives exactly what you wanted (at least if you use  a syntactic correct input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
yourList 
|> List.map (Array.filter ((<>)  condition))
```

for your example:

```
[[|"hi";"hello";"hello"|];[|"hello";"hi";"hello"|];[|"hi";"hi";"hello"|]]
|> List.map (Array.filter ((<>)  "hi"))
```

gives in fsharpi:

```
>  [[|"hi";"hello";"hello"|];[|"hello";"hi";"hello"|];[|"hi";"hi";"hello"|]] |> List.map (Array.filter ((<>) "hi"));;
val it : string [] list =
  [[|"hello"; "hello"|]; [|"hello"; "hello"|]; [|"hello"|]]
```

pls note that you have to use `"` and `;` instead of `,` (or you get tuples of undefined symbols)

if you want a function to mark all elements that should get skiped like this:

```
let shouldGo (s : string) : bool =
  s <> "hi"
```

(note every function `string -> bool` will do - it will remove all array-elements `a` where `shouldGo a = true`)

you just have to modifiy it like this:

```
myList
|> List.map (Array.filter (shouldGo >> not)) // yeah it reads strange - that's filters fault
```

or you can have a generic function:

```
let filterOut (shouldGo : 'a -> bool) =
  List.map (Array.filter (shouldGo >> not))
```

and use it like this:

```
myList |> filterOut ((=) "hi")
```

don't know what else I could add ;)

if you need a transform befor you filter you can use this

```
let mapAndFilterOut (f : 'a -> 'b) (shouldGo : 'b -> bool) =
   List.map (Array.filter (f >> shouldGo >> not))
```

you would call this for your picture like this (assuming x is your array-value):

```
likes |> mapAndFilter (fun x -> string (dataohumano TodosLosHumanos 0 x 3)) ((<>) genero)
```

but I think you should start and experiment for yourself a bit ;)
(as this did start on false assumptions, like you want to filter-out but here it seems you want just to filter, the examples are getting a bit strange)

PS: in your *special case* do this:

```
let likesFiltradosGenero genero likes =
  let mapF x = string (datoHumano Todos LosHumanos 0 x 3)
  let filterF =
      match genero with
      | "h" -> mapF >> ((=) "h")
      | "m" -> mapF >> ((<>) "m")
      | g -> failwith ("unexpected genero: " + g)
  likes 
  |> List.map (Array.filter filterF)
```

PPS: I would rename those `mapF` and `filterF` to reveal their indent but I don't understand spanish (?) even if I could guess that "genero" is "gender"?

Comment: and what if I need to call a function for each element on the array and then compare the result with the condition?

Comment: before or after the filtering? (or during it?)

Comment: as I said in the comment - just use such a condition instead of `(<>) "hi"` possible with `not` to *filter out* I add something

Comment: `((<>) "a string")` is just shorthand for `(fun x -> x <> "a string")`. So if you needed to call another function, you can do it inside the labmda.

Comment: I cannot see all your types and you should really start to try it yourself - this message is because you are using it inside a pattern-match and the first branch gives you a wrong type - so it wants the second to have the same type (the wrong one imho) - so you have to change the line with `| "h" -> likes ...`

Comment: the first line is missing the `x` behind `... = genero) x)` **<- here** again

Comment: yeah ... your first **case** is still wrong (the **x** *again*)

Comment: yeah I realized that, I didn't see your last comment until after I commented. Thanks for your help

Comment: yeah genero is Gender... ill change them.. but one problem that im having is that in return the arrays are returning "m" or "h" but I need them to return the initial information

Comment: I changed it (sorry again - realls stupid mistake) - I hope this all typechecks, as I did not check (don't have all the code)

Comment: PS: of couse you can *include* everything into the `filter`-function and use the first version or just the very last (and indeed I would do it)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you question, you have a list of arrays of strings, something like:

```ml
let source = [ [| "abc"; "def" |]; [|"ghi"; "abc" |] ]
```

If you don't need to keep track of which array the filtered string belongs to, I would do this:

```ml
source |> List.collect (List.ofArray) |> List.filter (fun x -> x = "abc")
```